# Как запустить проект в android эмуляторе?

Tags: эмулятор, android, cocos2d

Проект на `Cocos2dx` версии 2 для андроида не запускается в андроид эмуляторе на win7. Кто-нибудь знает, как выйти из положения?

Comment: Чего логи выдают? Например для запуска andengine приложений нужна поддержка gpu (но работает он все равно медленно, по крайней мере у меня, отказался в пользу отладки на устройствах)

Comment: Gpu simulation включена на виртуальном устройстве, а все скомпилированные приложения завершаются черным экраном. Логи даже не смотрел, так как проблема частая, а вот решений не видел.